# sphinx, rinohtype: inline code background color

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, rinohtype

How can we change background color of inline code.

One way i use inline code in restructured text is:

```
.. role::sql(code)
    :language: sql

You can use the query :sql:`select * from table` to execute...
```

When using `rst2pdf`, it outputs beautiful syntax highlighting and same background color as code-blocks. How can we achieve the same using `rinohtype`?

Ideally somthing `that looks like this in stackoverflow`

This is something i tried myself

`stylesheet:`

```
[code-paragraph: Paragraph(has_class="coder")]
background_color = #fdffd6
```

`and rst:`

```
.. role::sql(code)
    :language: sql
    :class: coder

You can use the query :sql:`select * from table` to execute...
```

but this didn't work, because `role` might be Text not Paragraph.

Comment: Note that there needs to be whitespace after `..role::`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, rinohtype [doesn't support setting a background color (or a border) for inline elements](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/issues/26#issuecomment-705450963). While we wait for that functionality to materialize, I'll discuss styling of inline text in general.

Here is the relevant part of the [stylelog](https://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/elementstyling.html#style-logs) for your reStructuredText snippet:

```text
Paragraph('You can use the query select * f...')   inline_code.rst:6 <paragraph>
     > (0,0,0,0,2) body
  MixedStyledText('You can use the query select * f...')
    SingleStyledText('You can use the query ')
    MixedStyledText('select * from table', style='monospaced')   None:None <literal>
         > (0,0,1,0,1) monospaced
      MixedStyledText('select')   None:None <inline>
        SingleStyledText('select')
      ...
```

The element you want to match with a selector is the *MixedStyledText* with the *monospaced* style. Because it's hard to predict whether you need to match *SingleStyledText* or *MixedStyledText* elements, you should **always use the more general *[StyledText](https://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/api/paragraph.html#rinoh.text.StyledText)* for selectors**.

For your example, the *code-paragraph* definition in the style sheet will thus look like this:

```ini
[inline-code: StyledText('monospaced', has_class='coder')]
base = monospaced
background_color = #fdffd6
```

Two remarks about this:

- Since the *style* specified in a selector has a larger weight than the *class*, you need to specify it in addition to the *has_class* argument, or increase the selector's priority. Read [Selectors](https://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/elementstyling.html#selectors) for details.
- Set the *base* of the style to *monospaced* to inherit the properties of the standard *monospaced* style. Otherwise you will likely need to set the *typeface* and other attributes as well.

For now, rinohtype will abort with `TypeError: background_color is not a supported attribute for TextStyle`. See the documentation for [TextStyle](https://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/style/rinoh.text.TextStyle.html) to see which style attributes are supported.

For further reading, see [Element Styling](https://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/elementstyling.html) in the rinohtype manual.